# What does this script do?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and am having trouble understanding this embedded script. Could someone please explain it to me the meaning of the code and how it works? Your time and help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<body>
    <div class="trapdoor">
        <div class="top door">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom door">
        </div>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/twholman" 
           class="twitter-follow-button" 
           data-show-count="false" 
           data-size="large" 
           data-dnt="false">
            Follow @twholman
        </a>
        <script>!function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                    js = d.createElement(s);
                    js.id = id;
                    js.src = "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }
            }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: is this script works?

Comment: yes it does, but I'm having trouble understanding how it works. Please help!!

Comment: (function (d,s,id){ } )();

Comment: It's a very common, basic IIFE that loads twitters `widgets.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said, this function loads a Twitter widget. Here's a quick n' dirty explanation by line.

```
// shorthand for a self-invoking function that accepts 3 named arguments
!function (d, s, id) { 

    // defines 2 variables, the second being the first "s" element 
    // in the document (zero-based index)
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; 

    // checks whether the element with passed-in ID doesn't exist
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) { 

        // if not, create it
        js = d.createElement(s); 

        // assign the earlier argument as an ID property of the element
        js.id = id; 

        // define the source property of the element
        js.src = "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; 

        // add the element to the document
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); 
    }

// name and scope the function
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as:

```
<script>

//If the twitter SCRIPT element doesn't exist in the document yet...
if(!document.getElementById('twitter-wjs'))
{
    //Make a new script element
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    //set its id so we know it exists after we insert into the document
    s.id='twitter-wjs';
    //the external script we want to run
    s.src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    //The first script block in the document, which could be this one
    var firstScript=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    //Now we insert our new external script before the first script in the document
    firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(s, firstScript);
}
</script>
```

Except it doesn't pollute the global variables in the document because it's a self-running function.

Answer (score 1):

It is self invoking function invoked with three parameter  document and strings "script" & "twitter-wjs". If "twitter-wjs" id is not found in document, it create 
script tag with src & id & inserts the script in script tag list.

Answer (score 0):

if donot exist the script with an id twitter-wjs, then insert  a script with a src equels http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js. And it's self-executed.